# Geodesic Curvature of a curve on a surface with a metric

Tags: differential-geometry

This is a problem from a past comprehensive exam:

> Find the geodesic curvature of the curve $\alpha(t) = (t,y_0)$ on a geometric surface endowed with a metric $ds^2 = f^2(x,y)(dx^2+dy^2)$ and the standard orientation

The definitions of geodesic curvature I'm familiar with are either as $||\nabla_{\alpha'}\alpha'||$ or $k_g = \frac{d\varphi}{ds}+\omega_{12}(\alpha')$ where $\varphi$ is the angle between $\alpha'$ and $E_1$ along $\alpha$.

Here's what I have so far: Using the metric we can define a frame field: $E_1 = \frac{1}{f}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, $E_2 = \frac{1}{f}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, we can write $\alpha'$ in this metric as follows: $$\alpha'(t) = (1,0) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} = fE_1$$

Here's where I come to a crossroads: Using the definition $||\nabla_{\alpha'}\alpha'||$ I believe that $k_g$ would be zero. The norm $||\alpha'|| = |f|$, so $\frac{d\frac{\alpha'}{||\alpha'||}}{dt} = 0$, yet if I try the other method I get a different answer.

I can compute $\theta_1 = f dx, \theta_2 = fdy$, so I found $\omega_{12} = \frac{-f_y}{f}dx+ \frac{f_x}{f}dy$, and the angle $\varphi$ between $\alpha' = fE_1$ and $E_1$ should just be zero, so $k_g = \omega_{12}(\alpha')\frac{dt}{ds} $ to rescale with the metric.

I'm not sure which one produces the right answer, and I'm a bit confused which one I slipped up on, does anyone see a flaw in either approach or perhaps have an easier way of doing this problem?

Edit: Fully written out let $s$ denote arc length parameterization along $\alpha$, by the chain rule 1= $||\frac{d\alpha}{ds} || = ||\frac{d\alpha}{dt} |||\frac{dt}{ds} |$, so $\frac{dt}{ds} = 1/f$. Now I want to compute \frac{d\frac{\alpha'}{||\alpha'||}}{dt}:

\begin{align}
\frac{d\frac{\alpha'}{||\alpha'||}}{ds}  &= \frac{d\frac{\alpha'}{||\alpha'||}}{dt} \frac{dt}{ds}\\
&= (E_1)'\frac{dt}{ds}
\end{align}
And the derivative should just be 0, since I'm taking the derivative of a constant: 1.

Comment: How did you get $0$ in the first computation? Please write out all the steps very carefully. And what is your final answer using moving frames?

Comment: But $E_1$ is *not* constant!

Comment: Ah! So we should have $\nabla_{\alpha'}E_1 \frac{dt}{ds} = \omega_{12}(\alpha')\frac{dt}{ds} E_2$

Comment: Yes, you should end up with $\omega_{12}(E_1)$ both times!